# What is the scope of a temporary index on a permanent table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Within a stored procedure, I created this index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX #IX_MyTempIndex ON dbo.MyPermTable (ColumnA, ColumnB) INCLUDE (ColumnC);
```

Days later, from a different session, a different user got the error "...an index or statistics with name '#IX_MyTempIndex' already exists on table 'dbo.MyPermTable'."

1) Is this the correct way to specify a temporary index on a permanent table? 
2) What event or scope will cause the temporary index to disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "Temporary Index".

You can make a temp table with an index, and by virtue of the table being temporary the index will be too, but that's not the same as what you're describing.

If you were allowed to make the index, why not keep the index that is necessary for your query?  Simply evaluate it and make sure it is a good index for your table.  You don't want an additional index that is super similar with only 1 additional column, or other inefficient scenario.

At this point you need to ask yourself some serious questions about the query you're running:

Are you aggregating items in this table, and only this table?
Are you joining to other tables?  How many?  Are they indexed properly?
How often is this table updated, deleted from, inserted into, etc?
How often is my procedure run?

Given the answer to these, and possibly other questions, you'll know if you should in fact have an index on the table.  Or, if you should be creating a temp table or view to do work on in your procedure.  In either case, you will not want to create an index, do some work, drop an index.  You'll lose more than you'll gain.

As an example, if you're doing some aggregations on values only in this table, and they take a while, it may be beneficial to simply copy the whole table into a view or temporary table.  This will release the base table from your locks faster than doing the aggregations, if not, just do your work on the base table.

If you will use it over and over, use a view, you won't have to recreate it each time, and it will be up to date when you run your sproc.  If performing your aggregations on the clone is still slow, you can put indexes on a view or temp table.

If you're sproc requires joins, you should probably be indexing the involved tables.  Otherwise, no matter what you do with one table, eventually the unoptimized table(s) involved are going to drag you down.

Answer (score 1):

Creating Indexes on permanent table through Stored procedure is not recommended.
This Index will be created on your permanent table and will be there forever unless you delete it. Please look at the below picture.

If you create Index on Temporary table, that will be dropped when the session end.

[image]